# how to Preview a file content in java?

Tags: java, file, file-io

I want to display a list of paths of multiples files and when a user click on selected path,the file of that path should be opened and display the content of the file (preview a file).so how do this on java???anyone know any idea?
help me please.

and I want do display the list of files like the search in windows (command +F).so i want to display the files in same form of displayed files in search in windows

which component in java do this form?

Comment: GUI libraries: Awt and Swing. But if it is your homework which must be ready by tomorrow, you lost.

Answer (score 2):

You can open a file with the (operating system) default application using the [Desktop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class, for example:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("somewhere/xyz.pdf"));
```

If you want to very safe, you can do this:

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported() && Desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN)) {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("somewhere/xyz.pdf"));
}
```

Opening various filetypes yourself would be a huge thing, requiring a huge amount of libraries, so I don't recommend it (unless you want to specify which file types you want to preview a little bit more exactly).

Comment: i want to preview :pdf and doc type ...but your code has an error : the method open is non static.how use your code?

Comment: Ups, my bad, you need to get an instance via `getDesktop()`, of course. Edited the answer. I would not suggest coding a pdf preview and doc preview in your application yourself, so opening them via `Desktop` seems a reasonable choice.

Comment: I want to display the list of files like the command +F in windows..whish component i have to use in java ?..

Comment: There is no default component that will show .pdf or .doc files in java, as far as I know, so you are out of luck there. There are probably libraries that can do so, never used one, though.